# how do i merge my swift code into existing objective c project by the use of bridge file

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode8, objective-c-swift-bridge, fairplay

i merge my swift classes in objective c existing project with the use of bridge.h file after than am not able to import my swift classes into my bridge.h files

[image]

Comment: are you create bridge header file?

Answer (score 0):

## import "YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-swift.h"

for your project it's

## import "Asianet_Mobile_TV_plus-swift.h"

For more info refer the following links:-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=afT92TQYpLQ
[How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this tutorial
 [Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

tip : when define swift class, you must use NSObject for implamantion class